# ChoiceField from model - Django - MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, forms, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm trying to make this work, with no success so far.

I'm using Django 1.6.5 and mongoengine 0.8.7.

I have some `ReferenceField` field types in my `models.py`, which I need to show in a `Choice Field` type, into a `forms.py` file.

So, these choices must be filled with the `queryset` from the referenced (or related models). So when I for example choose to register something in my app, I can relate for example 'users' to 'brands' or 'causes', etc...

Anyways, this was a brief explanation of what I'm trying to achieve with my app, here's my `models.py`:

```
from mongoengine import *


class Brand(DynamicDocument):
name = StringField(min_length=3,max_length=10,unique=True)
admins = ListField(ReferenceField("Peer", dbref=True))
campaigns = ListField(ReferenceField("Campaign"))
peers_partner =  ListField(ReferenceField("Peer"))
payments = ListField(ReferenceField("Payment_Campaign"))
medias = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField("Media"))
description = StringField(min_length=10,max_length=500)
socials = ListField(DictField())

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

@property
def pic_profile(self):
    for x in self.medias:
        if x.tag == "profile":
            return x.url

@property
def pic_banner(self):
    for x in self.medias:
        if x.tag == "banner":
            return x.url

@property
def video_profile(self):
    for x in self.medias:
        if x.tag == "video":
            return x.url
```

As you can see, there are some `ReferenceField` fields on my class, these are relationships with other models, but I'm still stuck trying to populate a choice field from `forms.py` with these references, here's my `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Fieldset, ButtonHolder, Submit, Field, Div
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from mongoengine.queryset import Q
from mongoengine import *
from hdb.brand.models import *

class Form_save_brand(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    admins =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Brand.objects.get_or_create(id=Peer),empty_label="")
    campaigns = forms.ChoiceField()
    peers_partner = forms.ChoiceField()
payments = forms.ChoiceField()
medias = forms.ChoiceField()
socials = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
        super(Form_save_brand, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['name'].initial = self.instance.name
            self.fields['admins'].initial = self.instance.admins
            self.fields['campaigns'].initial = self.instance.campaigns
            self.fields['peers_partner'].initial = self.instance.peers_partner
            self.fields['payments'].initial = self.instance.payments
            self.fields['medias'].initial = self.instance.medias
            self.fields['socials'].initial = self.instance.socials

    def save(self, commit=True):
        brand = self.instance if self.instance else Brand()
        brand.name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        brand.admins = self.cleaned_data['admins']
        brand.campaigns = self['campaigns']
        brand.peers_partner = self.cleaned_data['peers_partner']
        brand.payments = self.cleaned_data['payments']
        brand.medias = self.cleaned_data['medias']
        brand.socials = self.cleaned_data['socials']
        if commit:
            brand.save()

        return brand
```

The only field where I'm doing tests it's the fisrt `ReferenceField` (admins), which is where I'm stuck, if I manage to solve this I can continue with the other ones.

This is the traceback from Django:

```
NameError at /brand/nuevo/
name 'Peer' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9000/brand/nuevo/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'Peer' is not defined
Exception Location: /home/kkoci/hipeers/hweb/hweb/hweb/brand/forms.py in   Form_save_brand, line 11
Python Executable:  /home/kkoci/hipeers/hweb/hipeersweb/bin/python
```

As you can see right now the query it's like (id=Peer) but I've tried with (id=field), (id=name), etc... with no luck.

I hope I've explained myself...

Any ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please I'm stuck with this.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is how I initiliaze the form in `views.py`:

```
class AddBrand(CreateView):
model = Brand
form_class = Form_save_brand

def get_template_names(self):
    return ["brand/brand_nuevo.html"]

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('list')

def brand_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    messages.success(self.request, "The brand has been created.")
    return super(AddBrand, self).brand_valid(form)
```

Then in template `brand/brand_nuevo.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you initialize the form ? Either way I don't see a Peer field present in the form. You'll have to declare it.

Comment: Hi oglu, I've edited my question, yes, there's no Peer, BUT, Peer it's the other model, let's say this is model B, calling model A, from ListField(ReferenceField)), that's where I don't get it, how can I show this from a relational type field, then on ChoiceField populated from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you need is to instantiate the Form_save_brand with a specific peer so you can work out the dependencies and what is shown. This can be achieved by this (most of the code is kept the same)

You have to change the form to the following:

```
class Form_save_brand(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()

    campaigns = forms.ChoiceField()
    peers_partner = forms.ChoiceField()
    payments = forms.ChoiceField()
    medias = forms.ChoiceField()
    socials = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, peer, *args, **kwargs):
        # we pass a peer parameter that will be used in the queryset query
        self.instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
        self.fields['admins'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Brand.objects.get_or_create(id=peer),empty_label="")
```

and then, on your view

```
class AddBrand(CreateView):
    model = Brand
    # you don't need a form class here
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        return Form_save_brand(<you set the peer value here>, **self.get-form_kwargs())
```

Comment: Hi, wow, awesome! Going to try it right now, just one question, if I need for example, more than one field, like, let's say 'admins', I 'll have 'admins','campaigns','payments', etc... Should I add these to the same __init__ method?

Comment: Exactly. The idea is that you instantiate your form with whatever is needed to be rendered properly.